# What does the "accept rate" mean?

Tags: discussion

I searched the website and FAQ, but couldn't find an explanation of what the "accept rate" (that you sometimes see next to users' names) mean. Can someone explain?
How does the "accept rate" decrease or increase?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the percentage of questions asked by the user that have an accepted answer.

For example, I have asked 9 questions and accepted only 5 answers, so my acceptance rate should be 55%.

Comment: there's something wonky about the calculations though: Dana's accept rate should be 33% (2/6) but is displayed as 50%

Comment: The related MSO FAQ post about it is [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/how-does-accept-rate-work).

Comment: Thanks! I must confess I assumed something completely different :-)

Comment: BTW -- two of my questions are possibly "community wiki"s, i.e., no one answer is correct, and, hopefully, all the answers together form a good cover. They weren't tagged as "community wiki",though (not sure how to do it myself).

Comment: @Dana, right now only moderators can make a question community wiki. IMO community wiki is not a well-defined concept (as an evidence SE keeps changing its policy about it). I think it is better to keep the number of community wiki questions as little as possible, IMHO having no unique answer is not a sufficient reason to make them community wiki. I don't like making questions community wiki when the question/answers deserve reputations for the time/effort/knowledge their authors have put in writing them.

Comment: (right now the only major effect of making a question community wiki is that the question and its answers are not effected by votes anymore.)

Comment: @Kaveh Does the CW status of a question also affect the calculation of one's accept rate?

Comment: @Tyson, no, it doesn't, check the link in my comment above. (if accept rate is really important for you and it is only answered by all answers together, my suggestion is posting a CW answer summarizing the other answers and then accepting that answer.)

Comment: @Tyson: If you understand Kaveh’s reply, I have nothing to add to it, but in case his reply is confusing to you: whether a question is CW _affects_ calculation of the accept rate.  Namely, CW questions are excluded from calculation of the accept rate.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi Ito Thanks. I understand your response as the correct answer to my question.

Comment: @Kaveh As Tsuyoshi suspected, I didn't understand your response correctly.  I looked at your link above before, but didn't notice that the answer to my question was right in front of me. Thanks :)

Comment: Interestingly, accept rate is a poor metric for a site dedicated to research level questions. In the original Stack Overflow it was added to encourage askers to accept answers (who often wouldn't, thereby denying the reputation points to those who put in the hard work of writing answers). The key difference in the case of CS Theory is that questions have a definitive answer with far less frequency. In fact, someone who is asking very interesting and cutting edge research questions will have quite a poor accept rate!